# How to set a unique class for each item in an iteration? (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components

In a Lightning Web Component, I am displaying a list of images.  I want to change how the image is displayed on mouse over (hover).  How can I determine which item from the list triggered the event?

Template

```
<template>
    <template for:each={apps} for:item="app">
        <div key={app.index}>
            <img src={app.image} alt={app.altText} onclick={navigateToAppPage}
            class={avatar} id={app.index} value={app.index} name="appList" 
            onmouseover={handleHover} onmouseout={handleMouseOut}>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Javascript

```
 @track avatar = "slds-avatar slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small";

   handleHover(event) {
        this.avatar = "slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small";
        console.log("Hover:", event.target.value);
    }

    handleMouseOut(event) {
        this.avatar = "slds-avatar slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small";
        console.log("Out:", event);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bind the value to a variable, just use classList:

```
<img class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small" ...
```

Then, toggle the new class on mouse over/mouse out:

```
handleHover(event) {
    event.target.classList.add("slds-avatar--circle");
}

handleMouseOut(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("slds-avatar--circle");
}
```

---

If you're worried about renders wiping out the CSS, then you'll need one class *per item*, not just a global item:

```
<img class={app.avatar} data-key={app.index} ...
```

To find the item to modify, use the app list:

```
handleHover(event) {
    var app = this.apps.find(app => app.index == event.target.dataset.key);
    app.avatar = "slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small";
}

handleMouseOut(event) {
    var app = this.apps.find(app => app.index == event.target.dataset.key);
    app.avatar = "slds-avatar slds-avatar--large slds-m-right_small";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the second option, but I'm getting a  [apps is not defined] error.

Comment: If I leave out the this.apps = [...apps]; it seems to work ok

Comment: @EricSmith Should have been `[...this.apps]`. Regardless, if it wasn't necessary, then that's good to know. I've edited this answer to reflect that. Glad I could help!